SVG line right to left
I have some SVG code that draws two lines from left to right.
I would like to flip this code from right to left. I have tried changing the settings with no luck.


.separator {
    height: 1.25rem;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: unset;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
<svg class="separator" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 869 21" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line opacity="0.3" y1="20.5" x2="269" y2="20.5" stroke="#4EF4CB"></line> 
<line opacity="0.3" y1=".5" x2="1073" y2=".5" stroke="#4EF4CB"></line>
</svg>




The x values determine start and end locations. Just reverse them.

For some reason there is no x1 value stated but I would assume this defaults to 0

values can be viewBox coordinates or percentages
